# Segmentation fault в си, в чем ошибка?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Элементарный код, только начинаю вникать в си и не могу понять в чем ошибка. Если запускать без агрументов, то возвращается очевидный ответ "retry", если передать аргумент, то segmentation fault. В чем ошибка?
Спасибо!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int isdigit();
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2 && isdigit(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("%s\n", "### input text: ");
        string t = get_string();
        printf("%s\n", t); //when function has be written, insert it here
    }
    else
    {
        printf("retry\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: много замечаний в коде. 1. argv - должно быть `char**` или подобное по размерности. 2. isdigit обьявлено без аргументов, а используется с аргументами

Comment: 3. t - нельзя отправлять в printf оно не ест string. Нужно `t.c_str()` писать.

Comment: `string argv[]` - это нормально, c_str писать не нужно. Для тех, кто в танке - https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.h (и это СИ).

Comment: @nick_n_a: `string` в CS50 это `char *`. То есть `argv` здесь правильно объявлено именно как `char **`. Функция `isdigit` объявлена не "без аргументов", а с *неопределенным количеством аргументов*. Вызывать такую функцию с одним аргументом вполне корректно.

Comment: @rootheaven: Зачем в вашем коде повторно объявляется стандартная функция `isdigit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы объявили функцию isdigit, но не написали ее тела. Но с другой стороны такая [функция есть](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) и даже с подходящей сигнатурой.

Поэтому, немного переименуем и допишем тело.

```
int myisdigit(string data)
{
    int l = strlen(data);
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if ((data[i] < '0') || (data[i] > '9')) {
             return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

и соответственно вызываем так

```
if (argc == 2 && myisdigit(argv[1]))
```